# Twitter Bootstrap Icon-bar not Displaying

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Only 2 of my three icon-bars show when I resize my browser. Previous answers show that people have not put their icon-bars in the right nav tag, however I have done this and it is all correct. My website is viewable [here,](http://www.franhaines.co.uk/paddlethewye/) but here is my code for header.php too:

```html
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div id="logo">
                       <a href="http://http://www.franhaines.co.uk/paddlethewye/"/> <img src="wp-content/themes/BareTheme/logo.png" alt="Paddle the Wye Logo" border="0" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this rule on your page:

```
span {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-family: centrale_sans_regularregular,helvetica;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 80;
```

}

from bootstrap.

The position absolute is breaking it; override position to be static or unset for span.icon-bar and it'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You overide the bootstrap styles with your own stylesheet.

You must remove or specify your code (http://www.franhaines.co.uk/style.css) like so:

```
span:not(.icon-bar) {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: centrale_sans_regularregular, helvetica;
  font-size: 30px;
  z-index: 80;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same Code Works Fine For Me.

```html
<link href = "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div id="logo">
                       <a href="http://http://www.franhaines.co.uk/paddlethewye/"/> <img src="wp-content/themes/BareTheme/logo.png" alt="Paddle the Wye Logo" border="0" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/salunkheganesh07/x6kwqtyn/)

Note: Bootstrap CSS from [Here](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css)

Comment: That's so odd, even when I strip it of all my custom CSS it doesn't show up. /: